# How to debug graphics driver in linux?

Tags: linux, gpu, linux-device-driver

I am new to linux kernel debugging. I have a radeon graphics card and I am doing some graphics driver development for my embedded system. Before making a custom driver for another radeon card, I want to know how the graphics driver behaves in linux. I have studied a bit on DRM, GEM/TTM, KMS, Framebuffers; but I want to see them actually happening on linux systems. I have Ubuntu system with kernel 3.10.x

I want to debug the driver and see the following. Please help how to do it.

1. How to access framebuffer and see what is currently being drawn. (This is more of a curiosity)
2. Wish to see how TTM and GART tables are maintained and interpret them(any link would also help) and KMS as my display is DVI-D
3. How DMA is playing role here. Can I begin without DMA (over PCI for time being etc..)
4. Minimal device driver requirement to draw some raw pixels on screen

Unlike linux, devices in my embedded system are not treated as files. So need to understand them and reinterpret them for  my system.

Plan is to make Mesa over it. Just I am in the beginning stage. So any help would be appreciated.

Thanks